# Can't open or download pdf or exe files online with any browser on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, pdf, lag

When I try to open for view or download pdf or exe files online, the browser keeps searching for a long time, and ultimately shows:

```
This site can't be reached. The connection was reset.
```

(followed by some suggestions that never worked). However, browsers open the pdf files (offline) from local storage very well. I have done everything regarding plugins and add-ons duly. Adobe Reader plugin is enabled in IE8. I have checked with firewall off. All other computers work fine on my local network connected to internet through a wifi router.

*Screenshots of Process Explorer*

[image: screen shot from scroll down]

[image: screen shot when opened procexp.exe]

Comment: can you open this? https://live.sysinternals.com/Procexp.exe if so do a screen capture and try save and upload.

Comment: the exe file got downloaded

Comment: so where's the screen shot of all your processes?

Comment: m looking for the way to upload screen shot. i m quite new to this site. Would u plz help me?

Comment: save in any paint program then click on edit then icon for image  then click to add file and browse your PC for file then upload

Comment: uploaded the screen shots @Tony Stewart

Answer (score 0):

- 1) Not enough Memory available Usage 93.86%  ( need 4GB min or run much leaner)
- 2) Too many Processes running 86  ( shoot for 50 by disabling useless startups in msconfig or uninstall)  30 is possible on a lean machine
- 3) CPU use 75% ( too high)
- 4) check for malware

You are only showing about half of your processes

Never heard of SurfCanister but Firefox was not pleased with their website

> **Your connection is not secure**
>
> The owner of **surfcanister.com** has configured their website improperly.
>   **To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not
>   connected to this website.**

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/87058/slow-computerbrowser-check-here-first;-it-may-not-be-malware/

IF YOU NEED HELP ASK A PRO  ..or myself

Comment: Earlier it used to work properly even with higher loads of processes. It is on a netbook with only ram capacity of 1 GB. problem started only after i formatted the partition and installed the windows fresh. i m checking now for malware.

Comment: 1GB is small for the security software you have (bloated)  get more RAM or dump the "bloatware"  Uninstall Quick Heal Internet Security or Quick Heal AntiVirus Pro

Comment: Your bloatware makes your PC run like it is infected. even if it is not, but it may be ..      - Starter by CodeStuff
    - !! Autoruns
    - !! System Explorer Free or Portable
    - AnVir TaskManager Free or AnVir TaskManager Portable
    - !! WinPatrol
    - StartupLite
    - Startup Manager Portable
    - WhatInStartup Portable
    - !! Mike Lin's Startup Control Panel